# Can I add one iOS device on two different apple developer accounts?

Tags: ios, udid

I have two developer account and one iOS device. Can I add one iOS device on two different apple developer accounts? (I mean UDID)

Answer (score 6):

I had a client's iPod under both my developer account and his developer account, and it worked for me, at least. When you consider that someone's UUID might be under several accounts (i.e. a beta tester) you'd have to think this is commonplace.

Answer (score 5):

Yes - I have done this myself.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can add an iOS device under multiple developer accounts.